# Proof Regarding Inner Product

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $(X,\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be an inner product space. Show that if $\langle x,z \rangle = \langle y,z \rangle$ for all $z \in X$ then $x = y$

My attempt: We know that $$\langle x-y,z \rangle = \langle x,z \rangle - \langle y,z \rangle= 0$$ so by uniqueness $x-y = 0$ since this holds for all $z \in X$, and thus $x = y$ unless $z \in X$ is the orthogonal complement of $x-y$.

Im thinking maybe there is a better way to prove this since my result depends on $X$ not being the orthogonal complement of $x-y$?

Comment: If the equality holds for all $z$, then it holds for $z=x-y$. But that tells you that $\|x-y\|^2=0$ (by what you wrote) and thus $x-y=0$ so $x=y$.

Comment: The first comment is a perfect answer. The equality is given to hold for all $z$, whether they are in the orthogonal complement or not